# Negative binominal regression with aggregated data in Stata

Tags: regression, stata, negative-binomial-distribution, aggregation

A question concerning the effect of aggregation level on negative binominal regression estimates. Example with Stata.

Say I have the following data (showing first rows of an an example data):

```
clear
input gender agegroup education n_events person_years
1 1 0 101 55000
1 1 1 131 250200
1 1 2  5 10000
2 1 0 40 40000
2 1 1 50 240100
2 1 2 4 27020
1 2 0 130 44010
end
```

where

- gender is 1 men 2 women,
- agegroup 1 is 30-34 years, 2 is 35-39 etc.,
- education is 0 low 1 medium, 2 high-level,
- n_events is number of events of interest in the group defined by the gender, agegroup and education and
- person_yers is the number of person-years in the groups.

Say I want to evaluate the effect of gender on the incidence of the event, and I first do a negative binominal regression where I leave the variable education out:

```
*(a)
nbreg n_events i.gender i.agegroup, exposure(person_years) irr
```

but if I collpase the data to this level and run the same command, the results are different:

```
*(b)
collapse (sum) n_events=n_events person_years=person_years, by(gender agegroup)
nbreg n_events i.gender i.agegroup, exposure(person_years) irr
```

If I do Poisson regression instead for (a) and (b),

```
poisson n_events i.gender i.agegroup, exposure(person_years) irr
```

the estimates are exactly the same.

I wonder what in nbreg is causing this difference related to aggregation level, and what would be the coorect way do negative binominal regression to aggregated data like this? Should I always collapse the data first? Or am I missing something more fundamental here? Thanx!

EDIT: in this case, the n_events has variance of about 3000 times higher then the variance. That's why nbreg was considered appropriate. In the collapsed data, however, the variance is even higher.

Comment: What goodness-of-fit assessment did you do for the negative binomial model?

Comment: I added an edit, the dependant variable has a way bigger variance than mean. That's why nbreg came out.

Comment: That tells you which distribution not to use, but not which distribution to use.